# OSX move file with uneven number in file name

Tags: macos, bash

I have exported every frame of a video as `PNG` files of which I need to move every other frame to another directory. How can I move the files with odd numbers, e.g `intro_0001.png`, to a temporary directory?

An example of the file names are:

```
intro_0001.png
intro_0002.png
intro_0003.png
intro_0004.png
intro_0005.png
intro_0006.png
intro_0007.png
intro_0008.png
intro_0009.png
intro_0010.png
intro_0011.png
[...]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mv intro_???[13579].png tempdir/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is the simplest solution posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.png; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
    num=${file%.png}
    ((num = 10#${num#intro_}))
    ((num % 2)) && echo mv "${file}" "dir/"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (( i=1; i<=11; i+=2 )) ; do
    fn=$(printf "intro_%04d.png" $i)
    mv $fn temp
done
```